# Why do none of my labels or buttons appear?

Tags: java, swt

```
import customwidgets.widgets;

public class CharacterCreation {

    public static void charCreation() {
        Shell charCreate = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());
        //Shell represents a window within the application
        charCreate.setSize(500, 500);

        Label race = new Label(charCreate, 0);
        race.setText("Race");
        race.setLocation(0, 100);

        Label name = new Label(charCreate, 0);
        name.setText("Name");
        name.setLocation(0, 200);

        Label SPname = new Label(charCreate, 0);
        SPname.setText("SPname");
        SPname.setLocation(0, 300);


        Button submit = new Button(charCreate, SWT.PUSH);
        submit.setText("Submit");
        submit.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                try {
                    createCharSheet(race.getText(), name.getText(), SPname.getText());
                    Label success = widgets.createLabel(charCreate, SWT.CENTER, "Character Created!");
                    success.setLocation(400,100);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });     
        Button close = widgets.createCloseButton(charCreate);
        close.setLocation(400, 400);
        charCreate.open();  
    }
```

This window is opened by a button in another file/window. Whenever that button is clocked, the window opens but none of the labels or buttons I added are in there. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

`setLocation` does not set the size of the controls so they are defaulting to a zero size. You can use `setBounds` instead:

```
Label race = new Label(charCreate, 0);
race.setText("Race");
race.setBounds(0, 100, 100, 20);

Label name = new Label(charCreate, 0);
name.setText("Name");
name.setBounds(0, 200, 100, 20);

Label SPname = new Label(charCreate, 0);
SPname.setText("SPname");
SPname.setBounds(0, 300, 100, 20);

....
```

However using locations and bounds is not good practice as the control sizes will not be adjusted for varying font sizes. Instead use [layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm):

```
Shell charCreate = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());

charCreate.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Label race = new Label(charCreate, 0);
race.setText("Race");

Label name = new Label(charCreate, 0);
name.setText("Name");

Label SPname = new Label(charCreate, 0);
SPname.setText("SPname");

....

charCreate.layout();
charCreate.pack();
```

Comment: Is there a way to layout specific sets of widgets? I want to have something like a rowLayout of text boxes and then a rowLayout of buttons underneath

Comment: GridLayout can lay out controls in lots of ways - read the link [Understanding Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)